# How to get startTouch and endTouch event/position in angular ng-swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i use ngSwipe module angular. how to get event or position of start touch and end touch position/event in this module? in fact i want to find height of start touch and end touch.

height = start_touch_position - end_touch_position